# Select left join, group by user name and get the last last row

Tags: mysql, group-by

I've tried to get last entry with this query but I just can't get last row (only the first):

```
select users.*,messages.*
from messages
LEFT JOIN users
  ON messages.messageBy=users.email 
where messageToUser='{loginUser}'
GROUP BY messageBy
```

Comment: try to add ORDER BY messages.id DESC (or whatever your messages PK is)

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions your use of GROUP BY is inappropriate. Perhaps you're after the DISTINCT operator (oh, and ORDER BY some_column LIMIT 1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get last record with group by then try the below query

```
select users.*,message.*
from  
    message
LEFT JOIN 
    users
ON 
    message.messageBy = users.email 
where 
    messageToUser=1
AND 
    messageid IN (SELECT max(messageid) FROM message GROUP BY messageBy)
GROUP BY 
    messageBy
ORDER BY 
    messageid DESC
```

rough demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cda6f/1

Comment: Thats i know but i need group too

Answer (score 0):

So, if you have any kind of id field or date stored in your message table, you could do:

```
SELECT
...
ORDER BY your_date_field DESC
LIMIT 1
```

OR

```
SELECT
...
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Otherwise you are left with using code to count the number of records returned and just get the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you want the last message from each user.

A stock solution looks like this...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN (SELECT my_grouping_id,MAX(my_ordering_id) max_my_ordering_id FROM my_table GROUP BY my_grouping_id) y
    ON y.my_grouping_id = x.my_grouping_id 
   AND y.max_my_ordering_id = x.my_ordering_id;
```